# Java fileReader not reading files properly

Tags: java

I am making a class that reads a file of numbers and should return them into my program. However, when I am reading in the file, the file just returns null even though there is a file that exists and has content in it. The code is as follows:

```
try {
        File help = new File("colours.txt");
        help.createNewFile();
        
        FileWriter myWriter = new FileWriter(help);
        myWriter.write("1 2 3 4 5 6 7");
        
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(help));
        String line = reader.readLine();

        while(line != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
            line = reader.readLine();
        }

        reader.close();
        myWriter.close();

    }catch(IOException e) {
        System.out.println("There was an error");
    }
```

Comment: You forgot to close the output file before trying to read it. You also forgot to write any line terminators to the file. And when you get an exception, print the exception, not just some text of your own devising. That only carries 1 bit of information: there was an error. You need more than that

Comment: NB The `createNewFile()` line is redundant and wasteful. `new FileWriter()` will create a new file, and in the process it will have to delete the one you created with `createNewFile()`. Don't write pointless and wasteful code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close the file so that your content is written to the hard disk before reading it.

```
 try {
            File help = new File("colours.txt");
            help.createNewFile();
            
            FileWriter myWriter = new FileWriter(help);
            myWriter.write("1 2 3 4 5 6 7");
            myWriter.close();
            //Close the file before reading it.
            //Your changes will be added to the file
    
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(help));
            String line = reader.readLine();
    
            while(line != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
                line = reader.readLine();
            }
    
            reader.close();
            myWriter.close();
    
        }catch(IOException e) {
            System.out.println("There was an error");
        }
```